# Radiation Experiment, Can back radiation increase temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, climate-science

I have just completed an experiments to determine if back radiation can increase the temperature of an object.
I wanted to perform an easy experiment that would emulate the effect of back radiation to an object that was also emitting radiation at around the same temperature.

I have two photographic lights on stands as in the photograph. I measured the temperature of these lights after they had been running for around thirty minutes with a radiation thermometer.

I had these lights a good distance apart as to not have the radiation influence one another. I also measured the ambient temperature of the room that was closed to prevent any influence from the external atmosphere. In the experiment the power was provide by a single source of electricity.

When I was satisfied that the temperature of each individual light had stabilized, I turned each light to face each other and positioned them 180mm apart and left them for over an hour.

[image: Photographic Lighting] [image: Studio Lamps][image: Temp Gun]

Results:
[image]

The final temperature of the lamps raised by only 1.4 C after more that an hour. I put this increase down to poor convection of heat in the static air of the room. I measured the radiation from the back of each light at a specific point in an effort to standardize results.

I have confidence this experiment demonstrates that two separate sources of radiation at the same or similar radiative output will not double the heat generated.

As claimed in climate science.
[image]

Comment: What is "atmospheric surface temperature?" and from where did you get the idea that back radiation from the atmosphere can raise it by 33C? The illustration shows the surface _of the Earth_ receiving 333 Watts per square meter of heat from "back radiation,"  But it does not show any temperatures at all.

Comment: Also, What part(s) of the illustration (if any) are the two lamps in your experiment supposed to represent? and why do you think that those lamps accurately model whatever it is?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The answer to your first Question What is "Atmospheric Surface Temperature" I would have thought this was self explanatory. It is the temperature as measured at the surface of the Planet by surface thermometers. Question two "What parts of the illustration are the two lamps supposed to represent" Again I would have thought this was also self evident. The two lamps in the experiment represent two sources of radiation. If you like they could represent the radiation emitted from the surface of Earth or the radiation emitted from Earths atmosphere.

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot that your second question had two question. "And why do you think that those lamps accurately model whatever it is?" The answer is that I have not claimed they do represent what ever it is. The claim comes from Climate Science Lectures intermating  that atmospheric radiation increases the temperature of the atmosphere by 33C.

Comment: Answer to your "Re temperature Still unclear. The wording is correct I am discussing the Atmospheric temperature of the air. Not the surface temperature of the Earth. The reason for this is that the temperature of the Earth is far different from that the atmosphere.

Comment: I don't claim the two lamps accurately represent the Earth and Sky. They represent two distinct sources of radiation only. Again I am testing a claim by Science that Earth's temperature is enhanced by 33C via back radiation.

Comment: *I am discussing the Atmospheric temperature of the air. Not the surface temperature of the Earth* You cannot treat these independently when discussing global warming.  These things are all connected in complex ways.

Comment: The temperature of the air and the temperature of surfaces can be measured and distinctly differ. I am not discussing Global Warming. I am testing an hypotheses that Earth's radiative power (temperature) is enhanced by back radiation. This hypotheses has purveyed without testing to my knowledge. That is why I did the experiment.

Comment: Thank you for your ill inform comment. I am well versed in most science discipline after 40 years of research. No I don't think I have a breakthrough in climate science, far from it. I have performed an experiment that produced results, it is repeatable and easy to do, and that is all.

Comment: I deleted the comment. It wasn't really fair. But it doesn't sound like you are understanding what people are telling you.

Comment: Thank you for deleting the comment. I am well practiced at dealing with insulting comments.

Comment: I think what is conceptually wrong is using the temperature of the light sources, as if they can be affected by the radiation of each other. The lights have an independent energy source, and particularly photography lights, whose output has to remain stable in order to be useful for good photographs, must have electronic ways of not overheating, i.e reducing the power to the light if the temperature gets high. A photography expert should be able to tell. Maybe if you repeat the experiment with two *surfaces* heated by the lamps  behind?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The lights don't have an automatic way of reducing there wattage output. If overheating is detected they just shut off.  They do have a dial on the rear that can reduce light intensity. Both lights for the experiment where turned to maximum output. Measurements of the radiation were not take from the light source directly. It was read from the rear backing plate of the light in every case from a specific point.

Comment: Further more it would not matter if there was a difference in output between the lights as the experiment was performed to determine a significant increase in heat output, It failed to demonstrate the claim that back radiation can contribute anomalous heating.

Comment: The actual question should appear in the body. The only question is in the title, and it is not sufficiently clear. (What is back radiation and are you interested in the specific experiment you performed, some aspect of climate science, or “back radiation” in general?) Also, why did you neglect the 1.4 deg increase? What magnitude increase did you expect and why? Please edit the question to provide those details

Comment: Dale All the necessary information is in the explanation of the experiment. Try reading it.

Answer (score 1):

> [When we say the Earth “absorbs radiation”,](https://climatescience.org/advanced-greenhouse-effect/) we mean that it absorbs energy from the sun, and releases it again as infrared radiation .

So an experiment that could show the mechanism in the laboratory, should have

1. the [spectrum of light from the sun,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance#Irradiance_on_Earth%27s_surface)

[image: sunrad]

> Solar irradiance spectrum above atmosphere and at surface

i.e.the frequencies of the lamps should have the spectrum of frequencies that the sun has, not only optical/visible

2. should have material that can absorb and re-emit those frequencies  in infrared frequencies that heat the surface.

You consider the material of the lamps can fulfill 2) but it is possible that the range of electromagnetic frequencies of your lamp is too small . It is possible  your 1.4C is a reasonable number for the available frequencies and the time taken for the experiment. (the day night cycle is 24 hours),

Comment: Climate science claims that infrared back radiation is the reason our atmosphere is warm enough for habitation. It is not required to prove the claim of the experiment that the spectrum of the Sun's radiation be emulated to mimic the Sun's multitude of frequencies and Wavelengths. Why would you think that a necessary criteria and would it make any difference to the infrared? I don't think so. Have you any proof the Sun produces a specific form of radiation. I know enough about radiation to say confidently you are using tobacco company disinformation.

Comment: did you look at the plot above? that is the energy coming from the sun, the orange is the one hitting the surface.  The infrared created that warms the atmosphere comes from the whole spectrum, you only have an increment pf the wavelengths that is absorbed and creates infrared and heat, there fore you find a small difference,

Comment: No you are incorrect. When there are two independent source of radiation of roughly equal radiative power there is no energy transfer this is elementary Physics.

Comment: But you are illuminating and measuring the "surface" of the covers of the radiation sources., not the sources themselves

Comment: Both were measured it made no difference, try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt to clarify a few things:

1. "Back Radiation" is not some special form of radiation. The atmosphere emits radiation, as expected, and this radiation has a certain frequencies spectrum (what is described as "thermal" or "longwave" radiation, as opposed to solar or "shortwave" radiation from the Sun). What is usually called "Back Radiation" is just the fraction of this radiation that is emmited in the direction towards the Earth's surface, i.e. downwards. Nothing mystical here.
2. The rise in global average temperature compared to an Earth without its atmosphere is the direct result of the Stefan-Boltzmann law combined with the Principle of Energy Conservation. Even the [most simplified model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealized_greenhouse_model), considering the atmosphere as a single homogeneous layer surrounding the planet, would give as a result a temperature raise at the surface. Today's estimations on how much lower would the average global temperature be without the atmosphere are only more precise, having taken into account a much more realistic approach of the atmosphere's complexity. But the fundamental laws are the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pat, A good explanation of Back Radiation in the atmosphere. The purpose of my experiment was an attempt to determine if it had any effect on surface temperature. I don't believe it has, for the reason the energy emitted from the surface of the Earth is greater than the energy emitted from the atmosphere. As per the Laws of Thermodynamics heat will move from an hot object to a cold.

Comment: Pat. I read the article from the link in your post. The Idealized greenhouse model, and have a question. The article reads,  "In this idealized model, the greenhouse gases cause the surface of the planet to be warmer than it would be without them" As if this was fact. My question is what empirical evidence exists to present this as fact.

Comment: Pat if you're struggling to find any empirical evidence. Perhaps this paper will assist. http://www.sciencepublishinggroup.com/journal/paperinfo?journalid=161&doi=10.11648/j.earth.20170606.18

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you use LED lights, which have a qualitatively different energy spectrum than what is of relevance to the climate of Earth, where what matters is blackbody radiation. Also, your setup does /in principle/ not replicate the relevant situation of Earth, since it uses two unrelated solid objects instead of one solid one and one gaseous one modeled after the situation on Earth, with a geometry that is all wrong, as you have two small parallel plates, not an all-covering atmosphere. Then your objects have vastly different absorption properties, reflection properties, and spectral properties, compared to those in the real system. Even the absolute temperature scale of your setup is not accurate. And there will be other limitations upon close inspection. In other words, your model is a very poor model of what is going on with Earth and the atmosphere.

Now, climate science is just physics too (read up on Venus...) and all that said, you /do/ set out to test a hypothesis by experiment, which is the right thing to do, so congratulations to that. You just need to be aware of the limitations of your setup when interpreting its results. The technical term for that is "evaluate systematic uncertainties" and even physics graduate students struggle with that

With all that context added: you /do/ observe heating by radiation (though I haven't fully understood whether that is indeed back-radiation) so given the crude model, that can be counted as a success to validate what is going on in the real system.

BTW, an easy and impressive way to demonstrate the atmospheric greenhouse effect is to shine a lamp (ideally an incandescent lamp) on a jar (or old acquarium) filled with CO2. You can produce CO2 with seltzers tablets or pouring vinegar on soda.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The comments on my experiment have basically misinterpreted its purpose. I had no intention to emulate the Radiative Spectrum of the Sun or the Climate System. Its purpose was to demonstrate the Laws of Physics in a simple and practical way. This is the equation for Radiative Heat Transfer: Q=σ(THot−TCold) and that was its purpose. If you think my experiment failed to demonstrate its intent. Your comments are welcome.

Comment: Why has my experiment  been marked down? It is not clear to me. Please explain.

Comment: I think I answered  your (first) comment in my answer to your question. Since you deal with LED lights, temperature is ill-defined. You are far from thermal equilibrium. Your setup lacks even approximate blackbody spectra.

Comment: rfi - Why would you think LED light would not produce heat? Why do you think the experiment is far from equilibrium? Why is blackbody spectra important?

Comment: LEDs do not emit a blackbody spectrum. What you measure with your IR is a fit assuming a blackbody spectrum. Blackbody spectra is how transmission of temperature becomes meaningful.